# Golang Use Program as a Module

Tags: go, import, module

There is a terminal text editor written in Go called Micro, and I had an idea that it could be used in a Go program I am trying to write as a way to input text. Essentially my program would call getTextFromMicro(), and this function would open Micro, allow the user to edit text, and when they are done and quit Micro, it returns the text as a string.

To build Micro, you can clone the repoistory and then cd into `micro/cmd/micro`. I tried importing this folder into my program as such: `github.com/zyedidia/micro/v2/cmd/micro`, however I get this error:

`import "github.com/zyedidia/micro/v2/cmd/micro" is a program, not an importable package`

I'm guessing this is because there is a `main` package in the imported folder.

Is there a way around this, or can you not use a go program as an import in another program?

Comment: `micro` could have been built with a library you could use for some purpose, but I don't see that architecture in the github project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a program, you can use `os.exec` for that. You can pass arguments, read the return value, redirect stdin, stderr and stdout. This way you can control external programs that you cannot modify.

In your case, however, you have the code to `Micro`, so you can just use the code from the main package and rewrite it as a usable library.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you can use `os.Exec`. You can also use [`go-memexec`](https://github.com/amenzhinsky/go-memexec).

Also, if I understand correctly, anything can be used instead of `Micro`. It can be literally anything, depending on the technologies used.